# Retornar barra lateral de extensões do vs

Tags: visual-studio-code

Como posso retornar o menu lateral com as extensões?
Antes tinha aquela barra lateral com ícones, fiz besteira e não tem mais

[foto do vscode]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbPC2.png

ps ainda não posso upar imagens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome dessa barra é 'barra de atividades' em português.

Você pode ocultar/mostrar pelo menu VER > APARÊNCIA > BARRA DE ATIVIDADES

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Grata pela resposta!